# MVC4,как сделать чтобы  по клику в таблице на строке открывалась нужная форма?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, javascript

Здравствуйте, у меня есть таблица, в ней столбец IDName, мне нужно по клику на строке вытащить значение IDName и передать это значение контроллеру.

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            IDClaim
        </th>
        <th>
            IDname
        </th>
        <th>
            Текущая задача
        </th>
        <th>
           Дата старта
        </th>
         </tr>
        </thead>    
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

       <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IDClaim)
            </td>
            <td id="IDName">
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IDName)
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:left" id="Content">
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
            </td>
            </tr>

    }
</table>
______

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() 
``{
        $('#example tbody tr').live('click', function () 
``{
        var nTds = $('td', this);
        var sClaim = $(nTds[1]).text();
        alert(sClaim)
        });
        });
</script>
```

Походу я что-то не того наделал)
Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: так а проблема-то в чем?

Comment: ну мне нужно по значению sClaim, открывать форму, т.е. у каждого значения sClaim будет своя форма.

Comment: ну так я еще раз спрошу - проблема-то в чем?

Comment: не получается передать значение sClaim контроллеру.

Comment: а как вы это пытаетесь делать? Во всяком случае, в вашем коде я этого не вижу

Comment: в этом и есть проблема, я не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Вам стоит использовать [AJAX][1]

[1]:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/